# Alternativa al "bottom navigation"

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, bottombar, android-bottom-nav-view

Me gustaría saber cuál es la mejor opción para tener algo como el *[bottom navivation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation/)* pero donde se puedan tener seleccionadas todas las opciones que se quieran (y ninguna tambien). El uso principal es tener un visor de capas, por lo que el usuario pueda seleccionar cuáles desea que sean visibles y cuales que sean invisibles. También me gustaría agregar, como en el *bottom navigation*, texto y un *XML image resource*.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score -1):

lo mejor seria crear un LinearLayout abajo de todo y que ese levante el xml que queres con botones, textos y lo que quiera.
usas en tu xml principal

```
<include layout="@layout/barra_abajo"/>
```

En la ubicacion que queres ese otro xml.
Igual tambien lo podes hacer con un LinearLayout poniendo ahi adentro lo que queres y listo.

Agrego lo que puse en los comentarios

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/bgapp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
 
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Texto de prueba"/>  
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero al introducir los xml como fondo del checkbox, estos me quedan excesivamente grande, no se ajustan al tamaño del layer, o cuando los fuerzo a que se ajusten, me salen recortados solamente con el trocito para que quepa.

Comment: Probaste poner un imageView ocupando todo el espacio del  LinearLayout de la barra de abajo y ahi la imagen y sobre eso poner los botones y demas? Ahi agregue en mi respuesta un ejemplo

Comment: Me podrías poner el ejemplo como si fueran checkboxes? con imagen alternativa (xml) y texto. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Aclarame bien lo de los checkboxes, io sea va una barra abajo, que va a tener una imagen de fondo, y ahi adentro van varios checkboxes para elegir las capas? yo lo haria con botones que al estar seleccionados cambien el color ademas de mostrar la capa y cuando lo vuelven a tocar haga lo inverso, podes usar switches tambien,

Comment: Ahi lo agregue en el codigo de mi respuesta, contame si te funciona y sino con gusto te sigo ayudando

Comment: Exacto, quiero una barra abajo igual que el bottom navigation. Donde pueda seleccionar o deseleccionar tantos elementos como quiera. Y añadirle una imagen. Es exactamente lo que has propuesto en tu ejemplo pero con imagen y texto alternativo. Como lo añadirias?
Gracias!

Comment: Agregue el TextView en mi ejemplo, hay algo mas que te este faltando?

Comment: Falta la imagen...

Comment: Es está linea
, En el imageView android:src="@drawable/bgapp